# Different view sizes in simulator depending on chosen device in Interface Builder Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a questions regarding the the constraints View Controller. I'd set two different classes of constraints for some buttons and views in my View Controllers in the interface builder. One for wR hR and one for wC hR. When i choose for example an ipad in the interface builder and run my app on an ipad simulator every thing works fine, same for an iphone in interface builder and a iphone simulator. But if i choose an ipad in the interface builder and run my app on an iphone simulator and a real device the constraints are not updated to the different frame sizes.

[Interface Builder for Ipad Pro 9.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtsJE.png)

[View on Ipad for Selected Ipad in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt3wz.jpg)

[Interface Builder for Iphone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gtUG.png)

[View on Ipad for Selected Iphone X in Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6efC.jpg)

Thank you!

**Update:**
Found the problem. The issue was not that the constraints were not working but that the bubbles were drawn in the wrong place.
But thank you all for your ideas!

Comment: This behaviour would indicate that your constraints are not set up correctly; there are either insufficient constraints or conflicting constraints.  Do you have any orange lines in your scene in Interface Builder, or constraint errors or warnings, either in Interface Builder or at runtime.

Comment: There are warnings for some constraints that they will maybe cause clipping, but i want this clipping for the optical effect.

Comment: You should edit your question to show the relevant constraints. This is almost certainly the cause of your problem.  The device selected in IB doesn't affect the runtime placement, except in that it provides some "default"  locations for things. With correct constraints these locations will be calculated at runtime.  For each object, autolayout needs to determine an x,y, width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. The issue was not that the constraints were not working but that the bubbles were drawn in the wrong place. But thank you all for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

try to add in `viewDidLoad`:

That force the view to update its layout immediately.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this unfortunately doesnt work

Comment: Did you test that scenario on real device?

Comment: Jup tested it on multiple real devices. I will update the question and add some screenshots